# input handelChange on object data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, spread

Here i have a state `Details` containing a object with `name:''` `age:''` `phone:''` etc ... and a handlechange function , which whenever there's a change in input it should update the `Details` . there is a problem with way i wrote the line `setDetails({...Details, e.target.name : e.target.value}`

i tried this

```
function Personal() {
    const [Details, setDetails] = useState({ name:'hahaha' ,age:20 ,phone:0000000000});
  
    const handleChange = (e)=>{
        setDetails({...Details, e.target.name : e.target.value})
    }
  
    return (
    <div className='personal-details'>
      <h2>Personal Details</h2>
      <input type="text" name='name' onChange={handleChange}/>
      <input type="number" name='age' onChange={handleChange}/>
      <input type="number" name='phone' onChange={handleChange}/>
      
      

    </div>
  )
}
```

what i want is whenever there's a change i the input it should update it in the `Details` without changeing the exsisting datas.

thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with your code is that you are trying to access the properties of the event object (e.target.name and e.target.value) within the object destructuring assignment. Instead, you should use the square bracket notation to access the properties dynamically like this ;

```
setDetails({...Details, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
```

This will correctly access the name and value properties of the event target, and update the appropriate key in the Details object.

Comment: How would i pass the data to its parent component. without adding any submit button. whenever there's a change in the input it should pass that data (here the state `details`)